# What is the preferred meaning of the ambiguous {path} tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Browsing through questions tagged with [path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path), I note that there is a roughly even split between two senses of the word:

- File system paths
- The graphical constructs

These two meanings have zero overlap. Which is the preferred usage?

---

Edit by doncherry:

This question has de facto been decided by virtue of the [Oct 26 tag wiki edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/79187/revisions) of [path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path). It now reads:

> paths give the location of bin directory which consists of latex executable files in any platform. Post installation it is important to set the path for the bin directory. use this tag for installation issues

Even though the edit was [approved by Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7534), I'm not sure it happened with this question in mind. Let's finish this discussion‽ I think Werner's answer is a good start.

Comment: Richard, I hope you don't mind my editing into your question.

Comment: That wiki description talks only about the path to executables. That's a very narrow interpretation of the lemma and doesn't match the [top questions for the lemma](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paths?sort=votes&pagesize=15).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, note that tags are added based on what the poster of the question specifies. As such, you are not forced to use only the existing tags. However, since this Q&A is mostly community-driven, users with at least 500 reputation have the [privilege to retag questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) - informally translates to "users who have been here for a while" - in order to adequately assess the category/tag that it should be filed under.

Secondly, 10k-users have [access to moderator tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) which allow them to see any new tags that have been created within a given time frame (today, last 2 days, last week/7 days, last 2 weeks/14 days, last month/30 days). There is some form of "responsibility" on these "users who have been here for quite a while longer" to make decisions on the validity of new tags, or change them via a retag if required. Some users (to isolate [@lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)) are retag daemons and try to organise the site accordingly.

Finally, and more in line with your question. I think the [path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) tag has more to do with "file systems path" than it has to do with drawings or "graphical structures", since the latter is predominantly covered by [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) or [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks) and the like; each of which has such a rich set of macros that it would be infeasible to have a tag specific to each "graphical structure" within them.

My suggestion would be to perhaps define [path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) as a synonym for [filesystem-access](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-access), or even rename [filesystem-access](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-access) to [file-system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system). Admittedly I am new to this kind of issue, so I hope my ramblings are understood.

Comment: Making {path} and {filesystem-access} synonyms of {file-system} sounds reasonable to me. Just making {path} a synonym of {filesystem-access} doesn't sound as good, since {filesystem-access} to me, as a not-too-hacky not-linux not-English user, sounds a bit scary/foreign/can't really imagine what that's supposed to be. When making {path} a synonym, all the graphics-path related questions would have to be sorted out, first. Perhaps a {path-drawing} tag for these? (I don't deal with graphics questions too much, so I don't know if that would be reasonable.)